# How to preserve keybindings when using multi-term.el in line mode?

Tags: emacs, terminal, key-bindings

In emacs (ver. 24.3), I have my forward-paragraph and backward-paragraph mapped to M-p and M-n instead of M-{ and M-}. It is easier for me to remember and use fluidly with C-p and C-n. I've recently started using multi-term to run most of my terminal work. However, when I switch to line-mode my custom bindings for forward and backward paragraph no longer work. It says 'empty input ring'. Oddly when I'm in char-mode, the C-p and C-n do what they are supposed to do (bringing up previous prompt entries), but my paragraph movements work.

So in short, my custom forward and backward paragraph bindings work in char-mode (where I don't really need them), but not in line-mode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See `term-bind-key-alist`, which includes `C-p`, `C-n`, `M-p`, and `M-n` by default. See also these passages from the EmacsWiki page [MultiTerm](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm).  The second especially seems relevant to your problem. These do not mention `term-line-mode` or `term-char-mode`, but I think they might give you a place to start.

---

[**Note 1**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm#KeyBindings)

- ‘term-unbind-key-list’ is a list of keys which emacs keeps for itself. By default it contains (“C-z” “C-c” “C-x” “C-h” “C-y” “”)
- ‘term-bind-key-alist’ is a list of keys and functions which you can use, for example to use Emacs style cursor movement to the multi-terminal. The default is long, so I’ll let you look it up yourself.

[**Note 2**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm#MoreKeyBindings)

- Because C-r is default keystroke for isearch-backward, for avoid conflict with C-r, i binding M-r to send “C-r” character to shell.
  You can use option term-bind-key-alist/term-unbind-key-list to binding/unbinding special keystroke in multi-term.el, and don’t use term-mode-hook. ☺ –- AndyStewart

---

Also, I don't see `term-line-mode` anywhere in `multi-term.el`. It looks as if it makes use only of `term-char-mode`.  See, for instance, `multi-term-keystroke-setup`.